# Log to windows event log on server 2012 etc

Tags: python, windows, logging, event-log

Python `logging` module has an `NTEventLogHandler` class, but the description implies that it only works on windows NT, windows 2000 and windows XP.

What I am getting on win-7 is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 414, in <module>
    logutil.init_booster_log()
  File "E:\app\logutil.py", line 89, in init_booster_log
    system_handler = _get_system_handler()
  File "E:\app\logutil.py", line 68, in _get_system_handler
    handler = logging.handlers.NTEventLogHandler("Cool App")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 971, in __init__
    self._welu.AddSourceToRegistry(appname, dllname, logtype)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\win32evtlogutil.py", line 35, in AddSourceToRegistry
    "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\EventLog\\%s\\%s" % (eventLogType, appName))
error: (5, 'RegCreateKey', 'Access is denied.')
(5, 'RegCreateKey', 'Access is denied.')
```

Is there a drop-in replacement `Handler` which works with windows server 2012?

Comment: `NTEventLogHandler` still works in Windows 7 through 10. I used an application name of "Python" to write some events. Then I verfied they were written by running `wevtutil qe Application /f:text /q:"*[System[Provider[@Name='Python']]]"`.

Comment: @eryksun I have posted the traceback I am getting

Comment: [Event Logging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363652) is deprecated in favor of the [Windows Event Log](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385780), but the APIs such as [`RegisterEventSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363678) and [`ReportEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363679) are still available.

Comment: One caveat, as you've experienced, is that creating the [provider registry key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363661) requires running as an administrator. Also if you use a virtual environment, the environment's path to "win32service.pyd" gets used for the provider key, but you can specify an alternate path using the `dllname` argument.

Comment: @eryksun I have tried again and it worked.  Code was the same, as was running as administrator.  Strange...

Comment: If you were denied access to the registry key, then the process was not running as an administrator. Note that if UAC is enabled, then an account that's in the Administrators group initially gets a restricted token. To get full administrator access requires elevating via "Run as administrator".

Comment: @eryksun that I did.  I am running the script from Far Manager run as administrator

Comment: The key `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Application` grants `KEY_ALL_ACCESS` to the `BUILTIN\Administrators` local group. If the process token had the Administrators SID enabled, then I agree that's really a strange failure. Did you try deleting the "Cool App" subkey that was created to test whether the failure can be reproduced?

Comment: I did now, it worked (the key was created again).  Although there is an antivirus running, perhaps it was blocking write access to registry when I ran the script the first time

Comment: I have confirmed it to be the antivirus thing.

Answer (score 2):

It should have worked fine if not for the antivirus, which was for some reason barring my script from writing to the registry (even when the script was being run with Administrator permissions).

Turns out `logging.handlers.NTEventLogHandler` works on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2012 just fine.